# How Configure app.config for HTTP Basic Authentication?

Tags: c#, http, soap, basic-authentication

I am developing a SOAP client using C#.  The web service requires HTTP Basic Authentication.  Can I configure the username and password in app.config?  Can u provide a sample?

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentication is a function of the web server not the application. You configure it in IIS.

If you need to control users through your app use forms Authentication.

Comment: Forms authentication is not for web services.